# Try this CSS snippet to make StackOverflow look better

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, design

Add this to the very bottom of StackOverflow's style sheet (or use stylish to test it)

```
a,div {-moz-border-radius:3px;-khtml-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;}
```

It instantly will soften all the hard edges for almost all the boxes on your site that drive my eyes crazy. The tags, etc. instantly become softer.

Unfortunately there are still a few items that don't have borders so it won't work on them (like the horizontal menu at the top of each page) but it's still a great improvement. This is subtle, but it makes a difference.

Comment: Apparently Stylish = https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/2108

Comment: $("a, div").css({borderRadius: 3});

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to only ever read SO with your eyes closed.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately there are still a few items that don't have borders so it won't work on them

`border-radius` works regardless of whether there's an actual border! If there's only a background it will still create rounded corners.

Thanks anyway, it does make SO look slightly better. :p